# Attribute fields exporting as org_name, I want it to stay as the original field name

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, ogr

I am exporting a QGIS map as a gpx file, and some of the attribute table fields I have added are turning into ogr_name or ogr_length etc. I need it to stay as the regular field name as I have to import it into another software that only accepts those original field names as categories.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the "regular field names" for the fields you referenced.

Comment: The GPX schema defines just a handful of attributes https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/. Additional attributes must be added through schema extensions. Could you add examples about what kind of data you have and what kind of GPX the other software requires?